# Aligning a small paragraph alongside a math equation?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align, vertical-alignment

I've been struggling with even describing my question - my apologies if it's already been asked before. I'm new to Latex and I'm trying to typeset something that looks like this:
[image]

Right now I have the following code which doesn't do the right thing:

```
\begin{equation*} 
Specific \; activity \; concentration = \myfrac[2pt]{Absorbance \; \times \; 60\, \frac{s}{min}\; \times \; 10^6 \; \times \; 0.3\,L}{1450\, M^{-1}cm^{-1} \; \times 1 \; cm \; \times \; 3\, mL} 
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

If anyone could let me know what would be the best way to achieve this, I'd be very thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should provide a MWE (Minimal Working Example)
- your equation is out of context, so meaning of used  units is not clear
- See if the following is what you after:

**Edit:** added options as suggested @egreg in his comment below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\mm}{M} % what quantity is M?

\begin{document}
\[
\parbox{7em}{\centering
             Specific\\ activity\\ concentration} 
    = \frac{\text{Absorbance}\times \qty{60}{\second\per\minute}
                \times 10^6 \times \qty{0.3}{\litre}}
           {\qty{1450}\per\mm\centi\metre} \times \qty{1}{\centi\metre}
                    \times \qty{3}{\milli\litre}}
\]
and as suggested @egreg:
\[
\begin{tabular}{c}Specific\\ activity\\ concentration\end{tabular}
    = \dfrac{\text{Absorbance}\times \qty{60}{\second\per\minute}
                \times 10^6 \times \qty{0.3}{\litre}}
           {\qty{1450}{\per\mm\per\centi\metre} \times \qty{1}{\centi\metre}
                    \times \qty{3}{\milli\litre}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry for the non-ideal post details - but your answer was absolutely perfect, it got me what I was looking for!! (and I learned some new things for better formatting too ) Thank you so much! 

Comment: @lumixrani, I had problems with understanding what unix is `M` (it is not defined in `˙siunitx` package). Actually all your units are quite strange. You should reconsider what they should present.

Comment: @Zarko Why not the much simpler `\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Specific \\ activity \\ concentration \end{tabular}` that doesn't require to guess a width?

Comment: @Zarko M was meant to be "molar concentration", like it's used in chemistry